# Remove the shortcut to add a new record on a field

Tags: lightning

[image]

New to Salesforce. Is there a way to remove this '+ New Project' shortcut? I don't want users to be able to create new projects, entries, etc.

Comment: Meanwhile you can upvote this idea :- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TvUBQA0

Answer (score 0):

You can prohibit users from creating new records in any specific object by removing the "Create" permission for that object in their Profile.

Simply disallow creation for your Project and Entry classes for users you do not wish to see this option.

For more resources, check out Trailhead's [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_security) module.

Comment: That's the same general Idea I said but I think there is another use case where you don't want to use perms. There were solutions in classic, I don't know about lightning.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you would want to just revoke their permissions to create a new project altogether.

If you don't want to do that than I wouldn't think you'd want to remove it from that list either as they can create the new project anyway so why make it extra hard for them?

In our case we did have a situation where we only wanted users to create opps from the contact page or lead conversions to ensure that a primary contact was populated. We were able to remove the "new" button from related lists and search layouts in classic. I can't speak to what that would take in lightning.

### UPDATE

I couldn't find any lightning solutions that allow customizing that list to remove the new button outside of perms.

If you do have a use-case like ours you can instead add validation rules and or trigger code to help prevent un-wanted creations of records without removing perms. Otherwise, perms is your only option.